# Firefox runs the compatibility checker each start up

Tags: firefox

I'm using Firefox 31 and every time I open it, it starts checking compatibility with addons, and when it finishes it sends me to release notes pages of different addons, like NoScript's. It acts as if it just updated when it didn't.

Why does this happen and how do I fix it? (It has been happening since FF 28 if I'm not mistaken.)

Comment: I am not sure of the details, but the option **Update Add-ons Automatically** in Add-ons Tools causes periodic checks for updates. If you look at Add-ons after you have been running for some time you will see several updates waiting for a restart and I _think_ that it is these pending updates which are installed, not a full search of all updates. You can try disabling the option if you really don't want this to happen, but I am quite happy with how it works, so I have never experimented. There are also several parameters in about:config controlling update interval, etc.

Comment: @AFH Appearently I had 10 add ons that needed to update, so I updated them, but the problem keeps occuring. What parameters in about:config can solve my problem?

Comment: The problem keeps occurring because add-ons keep being updated. Are you saying that that you disabled **Update Add-ons Automatically** and it is still happening? I searched the configuration screen for "update" and there were several likely-looking candidates, such as **extensions.update.interval**, but I can only guess what they all control.